# adding a yes/no field with Format = Yes/No

Tags: delphi, ms-access

I have Delphi 6 code that adds a bit field to an Access table.
I have been unable to get any code to set the 'Field Properties.General.Format' to Yes/No.
Within the existing table I have other bit fields with values of either 0 or 1 and their Format is 'Yes/No' so the existing fields display a checkbox.
The code that adds the field is...

```
ADOQuery1.SQL.Text := 'ALTER TABLE MKSystem ADD COLUMN Use_GMK Bit Default 0 not      Null';
ADOQuery1.ExecSQL;
```

**After I step through the ExeSQL code, I can view the DB and see that the 'Use_GMK' was added to the 'MKSystem' table and that its Default value is 0.  The column's 'Format' is blank.  I have tried everything that I can think of to set the Format to 'Yes/No' but I have been unsuccessful.**

After checking previous posts, I have not found any response as to how to set the **"Format"** for this Column to Yes/No

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5246080/ms-access-alter-table-add-a-new-boolean-column-with-default-value-set-to-false

Comment: From the accepted answer to the dupe: `Set prp = fld.CreateProperty("Format", dbText, "Yes/No")`

Answer (score 1):

This question is more link to database format. Does Access is able to create enumerator format ?

In other case, you should interpret the value after load the record and before show it *(in that case you need to implement code After Load Data and also Before Save)*.

using String format

```
const
  Enum[0] = 'NO';
  Enum[1] = 'YES';
begin
...
  showmessage(Enum[ADOQuery1.Fieldbyname('Use_GMK').asInteger]);
```

or using boolean format

```
const
  EnumBool[0] = false;
  EnumBool[1] = true;
begin
...
  CheckBox.checked := EnumBool[ADOQuery1.Fieldbyname('Use_GMK').asInteger];
```

or directly using boolean native

```
procedure TForm1.Button6Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  checkbox1.Checked := boolean(Button6.Tag);  // this line can maybe fulfill your needs
  if Button6.Tag = 0 then
    Button6.Tag := 1
  else
    Button6.Tag := 0;
End;
```

I hope it helps, as it should be the Database that store the proper values.
(MySQL have Enum type that allows this kind of things). In other case, just work on the values to convert "on the fly" before show it.